# Yocto Image Recipe and SRC_URI

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to bring in an extra file to a custom Yocto image recipe I created.

I am adding the SRC_URI (file://somefile) to my recipe but find that though Bitbake finds the file when I build the image, it does not place it in the work directory for the recipe (or anywhere for that matter).

If I do this in a non image recipe (not inheriting the core-image class) the file will be placed in the work directory for the recipe.

What am I missing here? Is it not possible to do this? Is it being overridden somewhere else by inheriting core-image? FYI I am using Morty.

Answer (score 3):

image.bbclass does:

```
do_fetch[noexec] = "1"
```

so you probably need to do something like:

```
python __anonymous() {
    d.delVarFlag("do_fetch", "noexec")
    d.delVarFlag("do_unpack", "noexec")
}
```

to undo that at least with current OE-Core master branch.

Comment: I had this working using what you suggested... but then I moved to the latest bitbake / master linux branch - and there were a few changes. Mostly have it all working again - but one of the items that is not working is the fetch/unpack not running. `image.bbclass` still has `do_fetch[noexec] = "1"`... I have not yet found the solution. Any ideas?

Comment: After some tinkering I added the do_fetch and do_unpack as "prerequisites" to my task with: `addtask my_task after do_fetch do_unpack so_other_tasks before do_build` - and that seemed to fix it. Not quite sure why that is now needed - its a bit odd - can't find any doc reference to why.... oh well, with bitbake "not sure why, but it seems to work now" are my usual solution to things!

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are not providing the parameters to it to pick the exact file. See more [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#git-fetcher) 
Also look at [this](http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/OEManual/recipes_directories.html) for open embedded directory structure.